# How to handle or supress warning in Katalon for Chrome browser "This type of file can harm you computer. Do you want to keep it anyway?"

Tags: selenium, webdriver, katalon-studio

I want to suppress the above alert mentioned in the title while running my Katalon scripts.

Attaching screenshots for same:

[image]

Comment: Could you input more detail on how/where did you got the message? any screenshot will help.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/594792/disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-nag-in-chrome?rq=1

Comment: Also, see [this post on Katalon forum](https://forum.katalon.com/t/how-to-use-not-in-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software-but-in-normal-mode/12866/2). Maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: updated the screen shots for the same

Answer (score 0):

It possible we have to run the chromedriver in safe mode.please try the below code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
        String downloadFilepath = "D:/MyDeskDownload";
        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
        chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true"); 
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the browser to automatically download files. The following is taken from Katalon [forum](https://forum.katalon.com/t/identifying-chrome-download-box/9952/2):

First you add Chrome preferences:

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>()
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadPath)
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false)
```

And then specify the path to ChromeDriver and add experimental options:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "DriverFactory.getChromeDriverPath()")
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs)
```

NOTE:

You will need to import the following (or press CTRL+SHIFT+O for automatic imports):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory
```